# Parsing data from javascript array and combine with simple html dom

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, simple-html-dom

There is a `js array` source in a remote server which updated day by day:

```
var io = new Array();
nsi[0] = new Array('','Frank','','Factory worker','Mercedes',374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Audi',1456.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[1] = new Array('','Joseph','','Bank Assistant','Volvo',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'BMW',1875.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[2] = new Array('','Travis','','Shop Assistant','Peugeot',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Ferrari',1866.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[3] = new Array('','Aaron','','Snow plower','Opel',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Lamborghini',1986.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);
```

I already done parsing a website (which also use the informations of this js array) with simple html dom (it was a simple table with lot of rows, and there are informations in every rows. There was no problem. But I would like to add extra informations to every row from this js array source.

Example:

```
row 1: x   d    s   f     + the extra informations from the js array  nsi[0]  nth elements, like Factory worker, 1456
row 2: z   3    e   g     + the extra informations from the js array  nsi[1]  nth elements  like Bank Assistant, 1875
row 3: 5   6    g   s     + the extra informations from the js array  nsi[2]  nth elements like Shop Assistant, 1866
row 4: g   b    z   3     + the extra informations from the js array  nsi[3]  nth elements  like Snow plower, 1986
```

this `js array` is running on a remote server, but I have no idea how to combine with simple html dom. (I am very unexperienced with js arrays, I should be very happy if someone explain how can I do this).

---

```
    <?php

include ("mysql.php");
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $html = file_get_html('source.php');

class persons {
        var $day;
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
        var $birth_city;


    function persons ($day, $first_name, $last_name, $birth_city){
                $this->first_name=$first_name;
        $this->last_name=$last_name;
                $this->birth_city=$birth_city;
        return $this;
    }
}

$i=0;

$day=$html->find('h3',0);
$day->plaintext;

foreach($html->find('table.workers') as $workers) 
{




    foreach ($workers->find('tr[class=white],tr[class=grey]') as $workersTR) {

$first_name=$workersTR->find('td[class=a1],td[class=a2]',0)->plaintext;
$last_name=$matchesTR->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$birth_city=$matchesTR->find('td[class=bc]');

$i++;

echo $first_name;
echo $last_name;
echo $birth_city;


    }
        }

?>
```

Comment: It would help a lot of you tried to format your code a little and provided some code that can demonstrate your desired result

Comment: I am updated my question with the finished code. I hope someone could help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible javascript based solution. It is written in regular javascript for simplicity, and I have removed most of the values to keep the example simple. Just use the link ignore the code; I've no idea how to paste it properly here.

http://jsfiddle.net/omikey/9gj0cyrt/1/

```
<table id="table">
</table>
<br>
Add Name: <input type="text" id="Name" />
Add Job: <input type="text" id="Job" />
Add Car: <input type="text" id="Car" />
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="addValues()">
    Submit
</button>

var nsi = new Array();
nsi[0] = new Array('','Frank','','Factory worker','Mercedes',374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Audi',1456.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[1] = new Array('','Joseph','','Bank Assistant','Volvo',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'BMW',1875.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[2] = new Array('','Travis','','Shop Assistant','Peugeot',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Ferrari',1866.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

nsi[3] = new Array('','Aaron','','Snow plower','Opel',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,'Lamborghini',1986.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);

window.refresh = function(){
var inner =
"<tr style='font-weight:600'>" +
    "<td>Name</td>" +
    "<td>Job</td>" +
    "<td>Car</td>" +
"</tr>"

for (var i = 0; i < nsi.length; i++)
{
    inner +=
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + nsi[i][1] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + nsi[i][3] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + nsi[i][12] + "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
}

var dom = document.getElementById("table");
dom.innerHTML = inner;
}

window.addValues = function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var job = document.getElementById("Job").value;
    var car = document.getElementById("Car").value;
    nsi[nsi.length] = new Array('',name,'',job,'Opel',397,374.0,26.2,76,181,'',75,car,1986.5,27.1,5 ,183,'',9,19,'','',16,3,4,4,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,2,1,9,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,0,0,2,1,2,4,3,4,5,'  3',' 16',55,25,25,55,25,25,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,3,2);
    refresh();
}

refresh();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your answer, but I need to add the extra informations from an array.js file from a remote server. An example: I need every 5th and every 12th data (or x th) from every array and I must to add to my finished simple html dom query rows. I hope I am clear. And I must add to the foreach after I echoed the results.   Like: First Name, Last Name, Birth City + the extra informations from the js array to every row